# Data Table Replacing Values

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, data.table

I need to replace certain values in my code with NA, using R datatable. The below code only seems to replace one of the values. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?
Thanks

```
test <- data.table(name=c("x","y"),num1 =c(1.5,444444), num2= c(2020, 9999), num3= c(NA, 666))

numeric_colnames <- c("num1","num2","num3")

test[, (numeric_colnames) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x %in% as.numeric(666,9999), as.numeric(NA), x)), .SDcols=numeric_colnames]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of `as.numeric(666,9999)` :

```
as.numeric(666,9999)
#[1] 666
```

Hence it is comparing it with only 666. You don't need `as.numeric` here :

```
library(data.table)
test<- data.table(name=c("x","y"),num1 =c(1.5,444444), 
                  num2= c(2020, 9999), num3= c(NA, 666))

numeric_colnames<- c("num1","num2","num3")

test[, (numeric_colnames) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          ifelse(x %in% c(666,9999), NA, x)), .SDcols=numeric_colnames]
test

#   name     num1 num2 num3
#1:    x      1.5 2020   NA
#2:    y 444444.0   NA   NA
```